# The group $\mathbb{Q}^\times / \left( \mathbb{Q}^\times \right)^2$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, number-theory

Does there exist a nice description of the group $\mathbb{Q}^\times / \left(  \mathbb{Q}^\times \right)^2$? What is its order?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/387580/the-group-mathbb-q-as-a-direct-product-sum#comment829295_387580), we see that $\mathbb Q^{\times}\cong \mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z\oplus\left(\bigoplus_{i=1}^{\infty}\mathbb Z\right)$. Continuing to write additively, $$2\left(\mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z\oplus\left(\bigoplus_{i=1}^{\infty}\mathbb Z\right)\right)=\bigoplus_{i=1}^\infty\mathbb 2\mathbb Z.$$ More precisely, the multiplication by $2$ turns a tuple $(a,b,c,\dots)$ with almost all terms zero into the tuple $(0,2b,2c,\dots)$.

It follows that $$\mathbb Q^\times/2\mathbb Q^\times\cong\mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z\oplus\bigoplus_{i=1}^\infty\mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z\cong\bigoplus_{i=1}^\infty\mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z.$$

Comment: I don't understand... you have found the isomorphism-type of $\mathbb{Q}^\times / 2\mathbb{Q}^\times$, not of $\mathbb{Q}^\times / \left( \mathbb{Q}^\times \right)^2$.

Comment: @Frankenstein: How so? $2{\bf Q}^\times$ is just the same as ${\bf Q}^\times$, so the quotient you speak of is trivial.

Comment: @Frankenstein I am writing everything additively in my post since the actual computations involve abelian groups that are usually written additively. Hence, my $\mathbb Q^\times/2\mathbb Q^\times$ is the same as your $\mathbb Q^\times/(\mathbb Q^\times)^2$. I will second tomasz's point that I did not find the iso-type of $\mathbb Q^\times/2\mathbb Q^\times$ as you would write it.

Comment: I was just tired... It's all clear now! Thanks