# $\operatorname{Aut}(\mathbb Q^*)$ =?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Group $\mathbb Q^*$ is rationals without $0$ under multiplication.

From [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/387580/the-group-mathbb-q-as-a-direct-product-sum)  we know 
$\mathbb Q^*\cong \mathbb Z_2 \times \bigoplus_{i=1}^{\infty} \mathbb Z$.

So what is $\text{Aut}(\mathbb Z_2 \times \bigoplus_{i=1}^{\infty} \mathbb Z)$?

**Update:**

One of my classmates told me that every element in $\operatorname{Aut}(\mathbb Z_2 \times \bigoplus_{i=1}^{\infty} \mathbb Z)$ is one-to-one correspond to ordered pairs $(\theta,\phi)$, $\theta \in \operatorname{Aut}(\bigoplus_{i=1}^{\infty} \mathbb Z)$, and $\phi \in \operatorname{Hom}(\bigoplus_{i=1}^{\infty} \mathbb Z,  \mathbb Z_2 )$.

All $\phi $ is $\bigotimes_{i=1}^{\infty} \mathbb Z_2$, but all $\theta$ is rather complicated, is part of $ \bigotimes_{i=1}^{\infty} (\bigoplus_{i=1}^{\infty} \mathbb Z)$, is all invertible elements in this **ring**: matrix in $\mathbb Z^{\infty \times \infty} $ with every column only finite matrix element nonzero.

Are these correct?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If we consider instead $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}\times F$, where $F$ is a free abelian group on a countable basis, the endomorphism ring can be represented as
$$\DeclareMathOperator{\Hom}{Hom}\DeclareMathOperator{\End}{End}
\begin{bmatrix}
\End(\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}) & \Hom(F,\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}) \\
\Hom(\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z},F) & \End(F)
\end{bmatrix}=
\begin{bmatrix}
\End(\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}) & \Hom(F,\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}) \\
0 & \End(F)
\end{bmatrix}
$$
An endomorphism is invertible if and only if both components in the diagonal are invertible, as it easy to show.

Now, as rings, $\End(\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z})=\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$, so an automorphism has $1$ in the top left corner.

The group of automorphisms is therefore $\Hom(F,\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z})\times\operatorname{Aut}(F)$ with the operation
$$
(f_1,g_1)(f_2,g_2)=(f_2+f_1g_2,g_1g_2)
$$

Comment: I think you are right.And in this case End($F$) is just GL$(\infty,\mathbb Z)$

Comment: @Andrews Yes, but that's not a much better description: column finite matrices indexed by the natural numbers which are invertible.

Comment: I think $\text{GL}(\infty,\mathbb{Z})$ has a different meaning.  At least in my experience, it denotes the direct limit of $\text{GL}(n,\mathbb{Z})$ under the inclusions $\text{GL}(n,\mathbb{Z})\hookrightarrow \text{GL}(n+1,\mathbb{Z})$ sending $$\textbf{X}\mapsto \begin{bmatrix}\textbf{X}&\textbf{0}\\\textbf{0}&1\end{bmatrix}$$ for each $\mathbf{X}\in\text{GL}(n,\mathbb{Z})$ (i.e, each element of $\text{GL}(\infty,\mathbb{Z})$ is *finitary*).  There are elements of $\text{Aut}(\mathbb{Z}^\omega)$ that is not finitary.