# Multiplicative group of the fraction field of a UFD

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, ring-theory, unique-factorization-domains

Multiplicative group of rational [$\mathbb Q^*\cong \mathbb Z_2 \times \bigoplus_{i=1}^{\infty} \mathbb Z$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/387580/the-group-mathbb-q-as-a-direct-product-sum).

My question:

> In general, how to characterize the multiplicative group $K^∗$ of the fraction field $K$ of a UFD  $R$ ?

Can we use the same method which was used in  $\mathbb Q^*$?

And is there any reference about this?

Thank you for your time and help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your general statement is totally false (note that the answer you linked stated that description for a *number field*, not for the field of fractions of an arbitrary UFD).  For one thing, the description you gave would say that $K^*$ is always countable, which is certainly wrong.  It's not even correct if you remove the restriction that the free part has countable rank: for instance, $\mathbb{C}$ is a UFD and is its own fraction field, and its multiplicative group has no nontrivial cyclic group as a direct summand (since it is divisible).

In general, if $R$ is a UFD, then the multiplicative group of the field of fractions of $R$ is isomorphic to $R^\times\times \bigoplus_I \mathbb{Z}$ where $I$ is the set of irreducible elements of $R$ (modulo units).  The proof is exactly the same as in the case of $\mathbb{Q}$.  Note though that the group $R^\times$ of units in $R$ can be much more complicated than just a cyclic group and $I$ could have any cardinality.